# JOGL, Animator, Scaling, Overlay

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, jogl

I have two graphics objects. Each object is made up of tens of thousands of triangle primitives. For the sake of this example, let`s just consider the two objects as triangles - blue triangle and orange triangles.

I want to draw the blue triangle once in the background, and use the animator to over lay the several orange triangles over the blue. Think about the blue triangle as a canvas and the orange triangles are drawn over them in a pattern. Now the canvas and the orange triangles are rotated as a whole. Also, how can I scale the whole set up and rotate them around a different axes?

In this example, I want all the orange triangles to over lay on the blue. 
Here is the SSCCE. If you see in the example, the blue triangles over lay on the orange. I want all the orange triangles  to be on top of blue.

Also, how do I clear the canvas from an external event like a button click and completely start redrawing the scene?

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GL2;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLCapabilities;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLEventListener;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile;
import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.Animator;

import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class MainWin implements GLEventListener {

private JFrame frame;
private int iter = 0;
private float rotAng = 0;
private GLProfile profile;
private GLCapabilities capabilities;
private GLCanvas canvas;
private Animator animator;
private int totIter = 15;
private float scaleFac = 1f;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                MainWin window = new MainWin();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public MainWin() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 450);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JButton btnZoom = new JButton("Zoom");
    btnZoom.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            zoomObj();
        }

        private void zoomObj() {
            canvas.invalidate();
            scaleFac -= 0.5f;
        }
    });
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnZoom, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    // Initilaize graphics profile, capabilites, canvas and animator
    profile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2);
    capabilities = new GLCapabilities(profile);
    capabilities.setNumSamples(2);
    capabilities.setSampleBuffers(true);
    canvas = new GLCanvas(capabilities);
    canvas.addGLEventListener(this);
    canvas.requestFocusInWindow();

    animator = new Animator();
    animator.add(canvas);
    animator.start();

    frame.getContentPane().add(canvas); // add to the frame
}

@Override
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    gl.glRotatef(15, 0, 1, 0); // rotate both blue and orange objects around Y axis
    gl.glScalef(scaleFac, scaleFac, scaleFac);

    //blue object
    gl.glPolygonMode(GL2.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL2.GL_FILL);
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_MULTISAMPLE);
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glCallList(2);
    gl.glPopMatrix();
    gl.glDisable(GL2.GL_MULTISAMPLE);

    // orange object
    gl.glPolygonMode(GL2.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL2.GL_LINE);
    if (iter < totIter) {
        iter++;
        rotAng = 5;
        gl.glRotatef((float) rotAng, 0, 0, 1); // rotate each iter by 5 aroung Z. Only the orange.
        gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_MULTISAMPLE);
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glCallList(1);
        gl.glPopMatrix();
        gl.glDisable(GL2.GL_MULTISAMPLE);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if (iter == totIter - 1) {
        animator.stop();
    }

    gl.glFlush();
}

@Override
public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
}

@Override
public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    gl.glClearColor(.0f, .0f, .2f, 0.9f);
    gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    // buffers for multisampling
    int buf[] = new int[1];
    int sbuf[] = new int[1];
    gl.glGetIntegerv(GL2.GL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS, buf, 0);
    gl.glGetIntegerv(GL2.GL_SAMPLES, sbuf, 0);

    initObj1(gl); // Orange
    initObj2(gl); // Blue
}

/**
 * Blue triangle. In actual code, this is a complicated 3D object made up of atleast a few tens of thousands of
 * primitives in a mesh.
 * 
 * @param gl
 */
private void initObj2(GL2 gl) {
    gl.glNewList(2, GL2.GL_COMPILE);
    gl.glColorMaterial(GL2.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_DIFFUSE);
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

    gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_TRIANGLES);
    gl.glColor4f(.2f, .5f, 0.8f, 0.5f);
    gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0, 0);
    gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0, 0);
    gl.glVertex3f(0, 0.5f, 0);
    gl.glEnd();
    gl.glEndList();
}

/**
 * Orange Triangle. In actual code, this is a complicated 3D object made up of atleast a few tens of thousands of
 * primitives in a mesh.
 * 
 * @param gl
 */
private void initObj1(GL2 gl) {
    gl.glNewList(1, GL2.GL_COMPILE);
    gl.glColorMaterial(GL2.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_DIFFUSE);
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

    gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_TRIANGLES);
    gl.glColor4f(.95f, .45f, 0.15f, 0.5f);
    gl.glVertex3f(-1, 0, 0);
    gl.glVertex3f(1, 0, 0);
    gl.glVertex3f(0, 1, 0);
    gl.glEnd();
    gl.glEndList();
}

@Override
public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
}

}
```

Comment: You can call glClear in display(GLAutoDrawable). You mustn't call Thread.sleep(long) in display(GLAutoDrawable) as this method should be executed repeatedly, your code makes no sense. Please look at my example: https://gist.github.com/gouessej/3420e2b6f632efdddf98 You can render the scene to a texture if you need to draw some triangles and use them as a "background".

Comment: By the way, the display lists are badly supported  in numerous drivers, even on old graphics cards, I don't advise you to use them.

Comment: In my actual code I not using Thread.sleep(long). I don`t want to use glClear() because I want all the iterations to be visible. All orange triangles should be placed atop the blue, blue should be in the background.

Comment: Also, regarding the lists - this is from an example I found using Multi sampling. How can I implement this without lists?

Comment: You call Thread.sleep(500); in display(GLAutoDrawable). You can simply call directly the drawing code inside the display list instead of calling glCallList. You can redraw the previous triangles at each iteration instead of refusing to use glClear.